# Unknown value in for loop for Luhn algorithm

Tags: c, for-loop, variables, cs50, luhn

i have this code and for some reasons i get a very large number at every iteration of the for loop and i can't figure out the logic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    long CARD, digits, digit, odd, sum;

// prompting the user for a positive card number and checking the length  
    do
    {
        CARD = get_long("Please insert your card number: ");
        digits = floor(log10(labs(CARD)) + 1);
    }
    while (digits < 9 || digits > 16);

// Getting every other digit from the end (starting with the second to last)and adding the digits together   
    for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++)
    {
        CARD /= 10;
            printf("%ld\n", CARD);
        odd = CARD % 10;
            printf("%ld\n", odd);
        sum = sum + odd;
            printf("%ld\n", sum);
        CARD /= 10;
    }
}
```

Ok, so i enter the number 1234567890 and pass the do-while loop and when i enter the for loop i get these values (first 3 i display):

123456789

9

140443976194473 (but i expect this to be 9)

Comment: You have not initialised `sum.` It should be defined as `long sum = 0;` or set to `0` before you use it.

Comment: Please also ensure that `long` on your system is larger than 32 bits, which won't hold the value `9876543210`. It is better to use strings to store card and phone numbers because they can contain one of more leading zeros, which are not recoverable when stored as integers.

Comment: the posted code seems to be missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>` for the function: `labs()`

Comment: the posted code contains the unused variable: `digit`.  Your compiler should have told you about this problem

Comment: suggest, rather than introducing the function: `labs()` to simply check that `digits` is >= 0.  I.E. after this line: `CARD = get_long("Please insert your card number: ");` insert: `if( CARD <0 ) continue;`  Especially since a CARD number is never negative

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised `sum.` It should be defined as `long sum = 0;` or set to `0` before you use it.
                    – Weather Vane