# How to iterate through an integer's digits in C?

Tags: c, loops

I need to somehow iterate through an integer in C without any advanced stuff. I don't really understand how modding a number by 10 has to do with this iteration, or how it magically returns the last integer. **Can someone explain how to do this and iterate through an integer and show me code in C please?**

My code is not working at all and literally just does nothing, there is no output. But please just show me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    printf("Enter a value.\n");
    int  x = 0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    while (x < 0)
    {
        printf("Enter another integer please.\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }
    int counter = 0;
    // tries to iterate through freaking integer but literally doesn't work or does nothing
    while (x > 0)
    {
        counter = counter + x;
        x = x % 10;
        
    }
    printf("The total sum of the integer's digits are %d\n", counter);


}
```

Comment: If you understand what modulus does, it should be obvious how it iterates through the digits.

Comment: i have no idea and it's not what working. can you please just help me or atleast show me the pseudo code? we never learned modulo and it's logic in high or college at any point and this stuff is really confusing me. how and why does mod interate through the digits and can you comment and show me the code please? why does modding by 10 work and why isn't my code working? please show me

Comment: You can simply iterate through a number's digits by inputting it as a string. You typed it digit by digit, and there they are, and is unlimited by the size an `int` can represent. But besides that, I suggest changing the loop to `while (x > 0) { counter += x % 10; x /= 10; }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several problems in your code.

The first is doing

```
x = scanf("%d", &x);
```

`scanf()` sets its argument `x` to the input, and then returns the number of variables that it assigned, which is `1`. Then the `x =` assignment replaces the input with `1`. So no matter what you enter, you're setting `x` to `1`. Just use `scanf("%d", &x)` without assigning to the variable as well.

The next problem is your code to loop through the digits. The `%` operator returns the remainder in a division. So `x % 10` returns the remainder when dividing `x` by `10`, which is the last digit of the number (e.g. `123 / 10` returns `12` with a remainder of `3`). When you do

```
x = x % 10;
```

you get into an infinite loop, because once you get to a single digit, you just keep setting `x` to itself (unless the last digit is `0`, which fails the `while (x > 0)` condition). That's why your program doesn't seem to do anything -- it never gets out of this loop.

You should be adding the last digit to `counter`, and then removing the last digit by *dividing* by 10. So the loop should be:

```
    while (x > 0)
    {
        counter = counter + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    }
```

The corrected code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    printf("Enter a value.\n");
    int  x = 0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    while (x < 0)
    {
        printf("Enter another integer please.\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }
    int counter = 0;
    while (x > 0)
    {
        counter = counter + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    printf("The total sum of the integer's digits are %d\n", counter);
}
```

Here's how modulus and division iterates through the digits.

Let's say you have a number `x = 5649`.

When you calculate `x % 10`, that returns the last digit, which is `9`.
Then you set `x = x / 10;`, which sets it to `564` -- the number without the last digit.

The next time through the loop, you calculate `x % 10`, which returns the last digit of this, which is `4`.
Then you set `x = x / 10;`, which sets it to `56` -- again, the number without the last digit.

The next time you calculate `x % 10`, which returns `6`. Then `x = x / 10` sets it to `5`.

The next time you calculate `x % 10`, which returns `5`. Then `x = x / 10` sets it to `0`.

Now the loop stops because the condition was `x > 0`, which is no longer true.

So as you can see, the loop steps through the digits from right to left, because each time it removes the last digit by dividing by 10. Meanwhile, you're adding each digit to `counter` when you do `counter = counter + x % 10;`

Comment: i am confused, 1) can you explain the infinite loop. why does my code go into an infinite loop when i do x = x % 10, shouldn't it get the last digit of the integer each time until it hits the first (last) digit? why does my program never exit the loop, and what's the issue with 0 being the last digit? 2) secondly, why does counter = counter + x % 10 work and why does THAT not create an infinite loop? 3) why does dividing by 10 after modding work / what does it do?

Comment: When `x` is `123`, `x % 10` is 3. So you set `x` to `3`. When `x` is `3`, `x %10` is also `3`, so you set `x` to `3` again. Now you're stuck in a loop.

Comment: But `x = x / 10` replaces `123` with `12`. Next time it replaces it with `1`, and the next time it replaces it with `0`, and the loop stops.

Comment: `counter = counter + x % 10` works because `x % 10` is the last digit, so you add this to `counter`, which is how you add together all the digits.

Comment: When you did `x = x % 10` you weren't removing the last digit, you were removing all the digits *except* the last digit. So you get stuck with the last digit forever.

Comment: And `counter = counter + x;` wasn't adding the digits, it was adding the whole number.

Comment: If you still don't understand, try doing it by hand on paper. Or add `printf()` statements that print each variable during the loop.

Comment: Also this is a good read: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: thanks for your help so far @barmar, but i have a few questions. first, why does x = x % 10 remove ALL the digits except the last digit. why is it stuck with the last digit forever. for example, apply it to these numbers: 5649 and 19038, why does it somehow strip all the numbers in the front but keep the one in the back?

Comment: second, why does counter = counter + x not work? why does it add the whole number? and lastly my question is this, how do you know to if you should mod by 10 first and divide by then 10 last, or divide by 10 first and mod by 10 last? how do you know? can you explain that?

Comment: `x % 10` returns the remainder after dividing by 10. When you divide 5649 by 10, you get 564 and a remainder of 9. So `x % 10` is `9`.

Comment: `x` is the whole number. So `counter = counter + x` adds the whole number to `counter`. How can you not understand that?

Comment: If you divide by 10 first, the last digit is already gone, so you can't add it to counter. So that's how you know to mod first.

Comment: This is all just simple arithmetic.

Comment: okay, you just did! anyways, i'm sure you just explained it but it flew over my had. question - let's say you needed to multiply every second digit by 2 (counting from the end again) and then if the product was 2 digits, you'd have to add the two digits. for ecample, 656. you need to iterate every second digits, and here the second digit is 5, so that produces 10. how would you set up the logic so that if the product is two digits, you 'split it' and add it to the counter? can you please tell me and perhaps add it to your reply? sorry for the bother

Comment: I've added a detailed explanation of how the iteration to the answer, please read it and see if it clears things up for you.

Comment: just read it and it's amazing, you are a god send. thank you

Comment: To get the second digit, you use mod 100 to get the last 2 digits, then divide by 10 to get the first of them. So `(656 % 100) / 10` will return `5`.

Comment: Then divide the number by 100 to remove the last 2 digits.

Comment: but i had a question, barmar. i have to do this as a 'second case' (it's called luhn's credit card algorithm). you have to iterate through the integer and multiply every second digit by 2. then, if the product of the digit * 2 gives you two digits, you ADD the two digits and then add it to the counter. for example in 1556 you would have 5 as the first second digit and it would be 5 * 2 = 10. but you don't add 10 to the counter, you add 1 + 0. so can you PLEASE tell me how to implement this logic? do i use an if statement or another while loop?

Comment: Don't do it this way. Make an array of numbers and iterate through the array.

Comment: could you add it to your reply (last bother of the night, sorry hear barmar). how would you implement such that IF the product of every second digit * 2 is equal to 2 digits, you split up the digits and then add THAT to the counter, not the individual product itself. i'm just so confused as to how to implement this - does this come after dividing by 100? also why do you divide by 100 and not 10 now all of a sudden? secondly how would you implement this logic (what while loop / if statement set up would you use). would you mind adding this to your reply. i've bothered you quite a bit, sorry

Comment: we're not allowed to use arrays, that's the whole catch. it's this mod 10 divide 10 logic only allowed, so please append the setup or logic to your reply. i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: No, I'm not going to add it to my reply. One question at a time.

Comment: This is your homework, the whole point of it is for you to figure it out.

Comment: I've given you all the basic building blocks. This is what programming is all about: figuring out how to combine these basic operations to do what you want. You won't learn if I write it for you.\

Comment: fine, but can you write here in the comments how would i set up this logic where for every second digit, i multiply by 2 and split the digit if it's two digits and add the SUM of those two digits to the counter rather than the product itself? how do i set it up, do i use another while loop or another if statement? does it come after the divide by 100 (if the statement or while loop). i'm so confused, and we're not allowed to use arrays in our logic

Comment: No, the whole point of the assignment is for you to figure out the logic on your own.

Comment: If you want to know if something is 2 digits, just check `if (x > 9)`

Comment: Please stop asking me for additional help. Go try and figure it out now. If you can't get it working, post a new question with the code you tried. Also, there are hundreds of questions about Luhn algorithm, just search for them.

Comment: @Shah Jacob - e. g. [Unknown value in for loop for Luhn algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006817/unknown-value-in-for-loop-for-luhn-algorithm)

Comment: @Barmar may I ask a couple of questions which I had?

Comment: It would be best if you posted a new question. This isn't a discussion forum.